# Xcode 5 attribute view disabled

Tags: xcode5

[image: XCode]

In XCode 4 when I clicked on the icons, I could switch off/on the attributes panel. Now, inXCode 5, I can't...option hidden?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is to select your xib and click on the right button like this :

[image]